# bootstrap table - popover in <th> with image and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make a popover in the table in th. Tell me how to do this.
This my code. Data from database.

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    animate: false,
    html: true,
    placement: 'left',
    template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
  
}).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() ;
}).mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).popover('show');
});
```

```html
<table id="table"   data-toggle="table" data-cache="false" data-show-columns="false" ata-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-search="true"  data-pagination="true" data-page-size="500" data-show-refresh="false"    data-url="data.php"  data-detail-view="true"  data-filter-control="true"  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"> 

      <thead class="btn-success">  
              <th data-field="zdjecie"  data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover"  data-formatter="imageFormatter" data-sortable="true" data-tooltip="true" > </th> 
              <th data-field="marka" data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Marka</th>
              <th data-field="model" data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Model</th>
              <th data-field="lcd"  data-sortable="true"  class="text-center">Wyświetlacz</th>
              <th data-field="cena"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Cena</th>
              <th data-field="numermodelu"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Numer Modelu</th>
              <th data-field="rodzajLCD" data-sortable="true"  class="text-center">Rodzaj Wyświetlacza</th>
              <th data-field="ppi"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Nasycenie</th>
              <th data-field="rozdzielczosc"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Rozdzielczość</th>
              
              <th data-field="najnizszacena"> </th>
     </thead>


                          </table>
```

Comment: `$("[data-toggle=popover]")` doesn't get you any DOM element. Your selector is wrong considering above shared HTML.

Comment: I took this from the examples available on the web. Example http://jsfiddle.net/qy9Az/2760/ . This code is code from bootstrap.

Comment: Why dosen't work this code?
    function imageFormatter(value, row) {
        return '<a href="index.php" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Option"  title="<br>aaavvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"><img src="'+value+'"   width= "50px" height= "50px" /></a>';

Comment: <script>
    $(".pop").popover({ trigger: "manual" , html: true, animation:false})
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
});  
</script>

Answer (score 0):

And this code is check?

```js
  function initTable() {
        // sometimes footer render error.
        setTimeout(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
        }, 200);
        $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
                'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table', function () {
            $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length);


            selections = getIdSelections();

        });
        $table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function (e, index, row, $detail) {
            if (index % 2 == 1) {
                $detail.html('Loading from ajax request...');
                $.get('LICENSE', function (res) {
                    $detail.html(res.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
                });
            }
        });
        $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
            console.log(name, args);
        });
        $remove.click(function () {
            var ids = getIdSelections();
            $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                field: 'id',
                values: ids
            });
            $remove.prop('disabled', true);
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('resetView', {
                height: getHeight()
            });
        });
    }
     
function imageFormatter(value, row) {
        return '<a  class="pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-content="Optional parameter: Skip if this was not requested<br>A placement group is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability  Zone. Using placement groups enables applications to get the full-bisection bandwidth   and low-latency network performance required for tightly coupled, node-to-node   communication typical of HPC applications.<br>                                    This only applies to cluster compute instances: cc2.8xlarge, cg1.4xlarge, cr1.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge and hs1.8xlarge.<br>                                    More info: <a href=&quot;http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Click here...</a>"  data-original-title="" title="aaa"><img src="'+value+'"   width= "50px" height= "50px" /></a>';
      }   
      function detailFormatter(value, row) {
 
          return '<p class="text-left" ><img src="images/ceneo.png">Sprawdź na ceneo cena od <a href="'+row.cena+'">'+row.cena+row.marka+ row.model+' </a></p>';
      }

 
 function getIdSelections() {
        return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
            return row.id
        });
    }

    function responseHandler(res) {
        $.each(res.rows, function (i, row) {
            row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1;
        });
        return res;
    }



    function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
        return [
            '<a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Like">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>',
            '</a>  ',
            '<a class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
            '</a>'
        ].join('');
    }

    window.operateEvents = {
        'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
            alert('You click like action, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        },
        'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
            $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                field: 'id',
                values: [row.id]
            });
        }
    };

    function totalTextFormatter(data) {
        return 'Total';
    }

    function totalNameFormatter(data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
            total += +(row.price.substring(1));
        });
        return '$' + total;
    }

    function getHeight() {
        return $(window).height() - $('h1').outerHeight(true);
    }

    $(function () {
        var scripts = [
                location.search.substring(1) || 'assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js',
                'assets/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js',
                'http://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js',
                'assets/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js',
                'http://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js'
            ],
            eachSeries = function (arr, iterator, callback) {
                callback = callback || function () {};
                if (!arr.length) {
                    return callback();
                }
                var completed = 0;
                var iterate = function () {
                    iterator(arr[completed], function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            callback(err);
                            callback = function () {};
                        }
                        else {
                            completed += 1;
                            if (completed >= arr.length) {
                                callback(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                iterate();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
                iterate();
            };

        eachSeries(scripts, getScript, initTable);
    });

    function getScript(url, callback) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;

        var done = false;
        // Attach handlers for all browsers
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState ||
                    this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                if (callback)
                    callback();

                // Handle memory leak in IE
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };

        head.appendChild(script);

        // We handle everything using the script element injection
        return undefined;
    }
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="table"      
   data-toggle="table"    
   data-toolbar="#toolbar" 
   data-search="true"  
   data-pagination="true" 
       
    data-detail-view="true"
     data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"  
           data-show-toggle="false"
           data-show-columns="true" 
           data-url="data.php"
             data-page-size="800"
           data-show-pagination-switch="true"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-url="data.php"
           data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
           data-show-footer="false"
           data-click-to-select="true" data-search="true"  data-pagination="true" data-page-size="100"   data-url="data.php"   > 
      <thead class="btn-success"> 
        
              <th data-field="zdjecie" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover"  data-formatter="imageFormatter" data-sortable="true" data-tooltip="true" > </th> 
              <th data-field="marka" data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Marka</th>
              <th data-field="model" data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Model</th>
              <th data-field="lcd"  data-sortable="true"  class="text-center">Wyświetlacz</th>
              <th data-field="cena"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Cena</th>
              <th data-field="numermodelu"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Numer Modelu</th>
              <th data-field="rodzajLCD" data-sortable="true"  class="text-center">Rodzaj Wyświetlacza</th>
              <th data-field="ppi"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Nasycenie</th>
              <th data-field="rozdzielczosc"  data-sortable="true" class="text-center" >Rozdzielczość</th>
              
             
          
     </thead>


                          </table>
```